Should we participate in Winter Bash 2012?
Last year the Gaming site hosted an event called Hat Dash, where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". 
For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor. I've included some examples from last year in the attachments.

We have the opportunity to participate this year. Should we? Up vote the answers below to help us decide.
This event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event. 
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally  anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available, just as we had on Gaming last year. 
The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

No we should not participate.

The nays have it. The opt in date was 28 Nov.

I wonder what would have happened if there was a tie? Would you have rolled (cryptographically secure) dice? :)

@Thomas, tempting though random.org probably would have been much easier

Yes we should participate in the event!
